# is there a workaround for installing Eclipse in MacbookPro running macOS 10.16 (Big Sur)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm studying Spring and Hibernate and the IDE I'm using is Eclipse (after years of using IntelliJ) but the thing is, every time I attempt to install Eclipse ether by using the installer or just downloading Eclipse JEE I come a across an installation error and can't move forward.

Here is the stacktrace of the error.
PS: I've been investigating and can't find anything related.

```
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    
    Process:               eclipse-inst [4686]
    Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/Eclipse Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse-inst
    Identifier:            org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.product
    Version:               1.17.0 (1.17.0.v20200610-0514)
    Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:        ??? [1]
    Responsible:           eclipse-inst [4686]
    User ID:               501
    
    Date/Time:             2020-08-14 08:06:40.452 -0400
    OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.16 (20A5343j)
    Report Version:        12
    Bridge OS Version:     5.0 (18P50347c)
    Anonymous UUID:        4148D75A-3E08-F11D-ECE7-4B3A70E9672E
    
    Sleep/Wake UUID:       912A59C5-0BFE-4085-94F6-2AB8CB24A2AF
    
    Time Awake Since Boot: 14000 seconds
    Time Since Wake:       1000 seconds
    
    System Integrity Protection: enabled
    
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    
    Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
    Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    
    Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
    Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
    Terminating Process:   exc handler [4686]
    
    Application Specific Information:
    *** CFRelease() called with NULL ***
    
    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff297f593e CFRelease.cold.1 + 14
    1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2965110f CFRelease + 108
    2   com.apple.JavaVM                0x00007fff2e436c61 MakeMatcher + 406
    3   com.apple.JavaVM                0x00007fff2e435804 CreateJVMDetector + 38
    4   com.apple.JavaVM                0x00007fff2e4375eb CheckForInstalledJavaRuntimes + 43
    5   dyld                            0x0000000015bcbebd ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 559
    6   dyld                            0x0000000015bcc2b8 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
    7   dyld                            0x0000000015bc6e78 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 492
    8   dyld                            0x0000000015bc4d90 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 188
    9   dyld                            0x0000000015bc4e30 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 82
    10  dyld                            0x0000000015bb6261 dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 82
    11  dyld                            0x0000000015bc0769 dlopen_internal + 609
    12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6aa3826f dlopen_internal(char const*, int, void*) + 177
    13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6aa2690e dlopen + 28
    14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff296ed352 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadBundle + 147
    15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff29765ada _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 503
    16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2972db6e CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 39
    17  eclipse_1902.so                 0x000000000df7a62e findSymbol + 62
    18  eclipse_1902.so                 0x000000000df78679 startJavaJNI + 89
    19  eclipse_1902.so                 0x000000000df74f44 _run + 5732
    20  eclipse_1902.so                 0x000000000df734c0 run + 432
    21  org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.product   0x000000000de689f7 original_main + 1319
    22  org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.product   0x000000000de693a7 main + 1655
    23  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6aa36851 start + 1
    
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6ac6e4b4 start_wqthread + 0
    
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6ac6e4b4 start_wqthread + 0
    
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6ac6e4b4 start_wqthread + 0
    
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6ac6e4b4 start_wqthread + 0
    
    Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
      rax: 0x00007fff29a06bc2  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000055  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
      rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007ffee1d957f8  rbp: 0x00007ffee1d957d0  rsp: 0x00007ffee1d957c8
       r8: 0x00000000000000a9   r9: 0x00000000000007fb  r10: 0x0000000000002520  r11: 0x0000000000000060
      r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x00006000026c8410  r14: 0x00006000039c8000  r15: 0x00006000008e9b40
      rip: 0x00007fff297f593e  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x00006000013fa008
      
    Logical CPU:     0
    Error Code:      0x00000000
    Trap Number:     6

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 18440
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=657.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=657.9M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=620.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=620.9M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CoreServices                       172K        1 
Foundation                          16K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           226.2M       31 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        5 
Stack                             10.0M        5 
VM_ALLOCATE                        732K       12 
__DATA                            23.2M      280 
__DATA_CONST                        32K        1 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       471.7M        7 
__OBJC_RO                         36.5M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2483K        2 
__TEXT                           186.3M      279 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
mapped file                       49.5M        8 
shared memory                       40K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.4G      646 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.0G      646
```

Comment: This is being investigated in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565913 , but for now, try starting with a package from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ and launching from the terminal, specifying the JVM to use with the `-vm` switch.

Comment: @nitind Thank you! I've followed a recommendation in that bug ticket and I've been able to fix both Eclipse 2020-06 and Spring Tool Suite 4. I already shared my solutions there, I will the same here.

Answer (score 2):

**Environment:** Running macOS BigSur (10.16) and java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14.

**Steps:** Go to Applications folder -> Right click on Eclipse/STS4 -> Click on Show Package Content -> Click on Contents -> open info.plist -> Paste this code replacing the  tags in the file.

```
<array>
    <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options, or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V -->
    <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>        
    <string>-keyring</string>
    <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>         
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

STS4 from OS Catalina version don`t work on OX BIGSUR.
Try spring-tool-suite-4-4.9.0.CI-B173-e4.18.0-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.dmg, can you downloading from http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html

My solution

Step 1: Use o updated Java SDK version "1.8.0_271"
Step 2: Dowloading an install STS from spring-tool-suite-4-4.9.0.CI-B173-e4.18.0-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.dmg **
Step 3: verify you Shell (STS4 don`t work whit zsh version) may be /bin/bash/, follow steps https://support.apple.com/es-us/HT208050
Step 4: Thanks for follow https://www.facebook.com/gestiondigitaladministrativa

** link http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html